# Can I exclude elements from being masked with -webkit-mask-image?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="excluded"></div>
    Some very long text, that is masked on the left
</div>
```

Looks like

[image]

The mask is created with

```
#wrapper {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), black 100px);
}
```

The full example is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guaf6/).

I want the div #excluded not be masked like the text inside the wrapper, is that possible without moving it outside of the wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things,it masks everything inside the wrapper. Your best bet would be to do something along the lines of

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="excluded"></div>
    <p>Some very long text, that is masked on the left.</p>
</div>
```

checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWbu6/) to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I plan to have much more content than just this text and I would prefer not wrapping everything again

Comment: By the sounds of the spec, you are going to have to. You should be grouping your HTML based on what you plan on doing with it. In this case, you want to mask part of it. It isn't very hard or time consuming to do.